# Selenium Click method performs click slightly outside the element boundary

Tags: java, reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I have an application created in ReactJS which also contains some EXTJS/jsp iframes inside it. Now when I try to click some anchor tag element (Hyperlink) using selenium click method it wasn't working. After some investigations, I found that the click is performed slightly above the element boundary. The selenium is able to identify the element using xpath but is unable to click the link correctly. Also tried using the action but it didn't work. Using offset is not an option as it relies too much on the screens resolution.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It will help us make you resolved if you share the HTML Dom code or site URL.

Comment: @MohamedSulaimaanSheriff Sorry but this is an internal application of our organization and we are not allowed to share the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can set the width and height of the page to become larger. Some elements overlaps if the page does not support smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

If your locator is inside the IFrame, you will need to do a switch to that IFrame and then perform the click action, and after you need to switch out from that IFrame:

*driver.switchTo().frame("your_iframe_name");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("your_locator")).click();*

After use one of these to switch back:

*driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();*

Also, there is another way to click on a element located inside an IFrame, by executing a js script.

*JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("your_locator"));*

Comment: I am already switching inside the iframe and performing the clicks. The only issue is with the location on which the click is performed. The element is identified but the click is performed slightly above the actual element.

Comment: if the click is performed on the above element, I'm thinking about the locator which may not be correctly taken. Are you 100% sure that you have correctly created the locator?

Comment: Yes I am sure the locator is correct. It does not click the above element but it clicks slightly above the required element.

Comment: Mmmm, ok, this is weird. Have you tried also JavascriptExecutor?